# VBA (Access) - How to scan through A table and export images as a pdf

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

How would I go about scanning through this table and exporting the images as a pdfs?
Any help would be great, I'm not very familiar with VBA, even if I was this seems to be a difficult problem. I'm creating a form with a button and on the click of that button I want to sort through the table and export each image as PDF.

--- Update (9/8/2103)---

To elaborate these seem to be image files(.tif) of legal documents that were scanned and added to a Table in a Access database. So now I have to take those scanned picture files from the image field in the table, which holds the actual image file and export each image as a PDF.

Comment: It is customary here to present some code examples of what have you tried already. You can edit the question and insert the code you have problem with.

Comment: I have no experience with VBA no code to show, looking for helpful tips or similar examples if someone has them.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "export each image as PDF."  Can you edit your post and elaborate, perhaps with an example? For example, are we talking about looping thru every field to look for images, or just 1? Are the images stored in the table itself or just filepaths to the images? It might help to give a thorough step-by-step.

Comment: I have update my original post. These are images of legal documents, many of them (10,000+) that are in one table of a database which holds the actual image file. I need to loop through each row in the table and export the image as a PDF.

Answer (score 0):

You might try to start with a report if what you want is the information in the table in a PDF form.  You can create a report under the "create" tab and use the Reports Wizard to input the fields that you want.  You can then easily export the report to a PDF, either by opening the report and manually clicking "PDF or XPS" under "Data" on the Print Preview tab of the ribbon or via VBA.  As PowerUser said, if you can give more detail about the table and field as well as how the images are stored that will also help answer this question more thoroughly.

Comment: The table includes the actual image file as well as the Image path. There are 10,000 plus document Images so this has to be automated. I need to loop through each record in the table and export each image as a PDF.